# Top 5 using range in column A that matches values range of column B

Tags: excel

```
[A]  [B]  [C]  [D]  [E]
ABC  DFC  20
DE   DE   12
     GF   11
     ABC  19
     DE   17
     DE   15
     XE   14
     ABC  10
```

I would like to put a top 5 in [column D] and [column E] of [column B] and [column C] using the range in [column A] as found in [column B].

Based on this example above, the end result in [D] and [E] should look like:

```
[D]  [E]
ABC  19
DE   17
DE   15
DE   12
ABC  10
```

Thanks in advance for your solution.

Edit: I should add. [Column A] is dynamic and could contain values in rows 2 to 6 (as an example).

Comment: {=LARGE(IF(B:B=A1,C:C,0),1)} So far I have this for [E] but it only uses the value found in [A1]. I need to use the range of [column A]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell E1 and copied down:

```
=IF(ROW(E1)>SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$8,$A$1:$A$6)),"",LARGE(INDEX((COUNTIF($A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$8)>0)*$C$1:$C$8,),ROW(E1)))
```

In cell D1 and copied down:

```
=IF(E1="","",INDEX($B$1:$B$8,MATCH(E1,$C$1:$C$8,0)))
```

Both formulas are regular formulas and do not require array entry.  In both cases, adjust the B and C column references to fit your actual data.  Don't use whole column references.  If necessary, use dynamic named ranges for the column B and C range references

**EDIT**: And just in case there are duplicates in the numeric values of the top five numbers for column C, use this formula instead in cell D1 and copy down:

```
=IF(E1="","",INDEX($B$1:$B$8,SMALL(INDEX(($C$1:$C$8=E1)*ROW($C$1:$C$8),),COUNTIF($C$1:$C$8,"<>"&E1)+COUNTIF(E$1:E1,E1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The newer [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can help retrieve the appropriate values as well as passing their associated row numbers to an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) to retrieve the names.

In E2:F2 as standard formulas,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(B$1:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, C:C)))/(C$1:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))=F2), COUNTIF(F$2:F2, F2)))
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))/ISNUMBER(MATCH(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, C:C)), A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz", A:A)), 0)), ROW(1:1))
```

Fill down for four more rows.

[image: top_5_aggregate]

Note that I've changed one of your values to demonstrate how duplicates are handled.