# Largest items from a list, no repetition (match/index)

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm looking to compile lists of 5 from my data set based on size. For example let's say sales per person.

I've used match/index and an array formula to return the name of the person and their sales (providing there are >3).

> **AF4** = LARGE($B$5:$B$59, *n*)

and

> **AE4** = INDEX($A$5:$A$59, MATCH(AF4, $B$5:$B$59, 0))

This has worked very well except for one flaw. If the **AF4** and **AF5** would both return 6, then **AE4** and **AE5** would return the same name twice, even if there are multiple people who would have made 6 sales. The name it picks is of course dependant on if the list is sorted in alphabetical order or any other way.

I've tried workaround using the IF function if two cells contain the same name but it always ends as a circular reference.

I'd appreciate any help or advice you might have to fix this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like [Top 5 using range in column A that matches values range of column B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654916/top-5-using-range-in-column-a-that-matches-values-range-of-column-b/36660120#36660120). There are [several other responses](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4039065+%5Bexcel%5Daggregate+countif) that use AGGREGATE with INDEX to get the second, third, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Change your formula in AE4 to this array formula:

```
= INDEX($A$5:$A$59, MATCH(1,(AF4= $B$5:$B$59)*(COUNTIF($AE$3:$AE3,$A$5:$A$59)=0), 0))
```

being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then copy the formula down.

[image]