# Finding the ten highest and lowest values and their associated labels in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have values in cells B2:B52 and each value's respective label in cells A2:A52. I am hoping to find the ten highest and ten lowest values within the column as well as the values' respective labels. Ties should not be a problem as the values are quite unique. As an example, here are the first five values and labels:

```
ALABAMA 0.363746457
ALASKA  0.632334359
ARIZONA 0.512511586
ARKANSAS    0.485002318
```

Thank you.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654916/top-5-using-range-in-column-a-that-matches-values-range-of-column-b/36660120#36660120

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

[image]

Use SMALL() for the lowest values